# statistics on several columns of data in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, col

I am going to find mean, median and ... of my data. However, I need to find these data for for example every 10 columns which there are some NA data in my columns. Can you guide me how I should do that, please.
Maybe this is a basic question but I could not find any posts regarding this.

Thank

Comment: yes all of them are numeric some include NA except the first column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `split` the dataset into `list` of `data.frame`

```
library(matrixStats)
lst1 <- split.default(df1, as.integer(gl(ncol(df1), 10, ncol(df1))))
```

If we need a single `mean/median`

```
sapply(lst1, function(x) mean(unlist(x), na.rm = TRUE))
sapply(lst1, function(x) median(unlist(x), na.rm = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:10), 25* 10, 
          replace = TRUE), ncol = 25))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need for example the median of each list

Comment: Sure, thanks for your time. I need the median of each 10 columns, not by each row (in your data ... we should have for example the median for each 100 data)

Comment: well to be more clear, I mean for your data I need three numbers (one mean for each list)